# Mainframes JCL Record transposing using SORT

Tags: mainframe, jcl, syncsort

I want to do following transposing of records into column using SORT (snycsort or DFSORT). It should be  scalable  to any number of records .Is this possible ?

```
DE001XYX   A 

CD100000   B 

CD200000   C 

DE001KKK   A 

CD100000   B 

DE003ZZZ   A 

DE001XYX   A 

CD100000   B 

CD200000   C 

DE001KKK   A 

CD100000   B 

........
```

Transpose

```
DE001XYX   CD100000   CD200000   
DE001KKK   CD100000   
DE003ZZZ   
DE001XYX   CD100000   CD200000   
DE001KKK   CD100000   
.....
```

Comment: Please let us know which SORT product you are using: DFSORT, Syncsort, etc. and add those tags to your question.

Comment: How could it scale to any number of records? You only have 26 letters of the alphabet, and you have maxima for record-lengths. Is the output order important (since the data needs to be sorted at least once already)?

Comment: There only three Keys namely A B C .A goes with record that start with DE, B goes with record that start with CD1 and C goes with record that start with CD2. The  each DE record is related to the record below it I.e CD1 and CD2 records.

Comment: If you're still tackling this issue why not use REXX?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is one question which I Favorited and longed to solve it myself for quite some time. After some research & try outs, I've just come up with a solution.

---

***UPDATE:*** Improvised approach is given below. It solves the problem in 1 pass itself whereas the initial approach took 3 passes.

**Improvised approach:** 
No need of 3 passes.

```
***************************** Top of Data ******************************
//JOBNAME JOB ('ACCOUNT INFORMATION'),'TRANSPOSE',                      
//     CLASS=2,MSGCLASS=H,NOTIFY=&SYSUID                                
//STEP1   EXEC PGM=SORT                                                 
//SORTIN  DD *                                                          
DE001XYX   A                                                            
CD100000   B                                                            
CD200000   C                                                            
DE001KKK   A                                                            
CD100000   B                                                            
DE003ZZZ   A                                                            
DE001XYX   A                                                            
CD100000   B                                                            
CD200000   C                                                            
DE001KKK   A                                                            
CD100000   B                                                            
//SORTOUT DD SYSOUT=*                                                   
//SYSOUT  DD SYSOUT=*                                                   
//SYSIN   DD *                                                          
 SORT FIELDS=(30,1,CH,A)                                                
 INREC IFTHEN=(WHEN=GROUP,BEGIN=(12,1,CH,EQ,C'A'),                      
              END=(12,1,CH,EQ,C'C'),PUSH=(14:ID=1)),                    
       IFTHEN=(WHEN=(12,1,CH,EQ,C'A'),BUILD=(1:1,8,19Z,28:12,1,         
              30:14,1)),                                                
       IFTHEN=(WHEN=(12,1,CH,EQ,C'B'),                                  
              BUILD=(1:9Z,10:1,8,18:10Z,28:12,1,30:14,1)),              
       IFTHEN=(WHEN=(12,1,CH,EQ,C'C'),                                  
              BUILD=(1:18Z,19:1,8,28:12,1,30:14,1))                     
 SUM FIELDS=(1,8,10,8,19,8),FORMAT=BI                                   
 OUTREC FIELDS=(1:1,8,9:X,10:10,8,18:X,19:19,8)                         
**************************** Bottom of Data ****************************
```

Results in the same output which OP has shown in his/her question.

---

**Initial approach:**

**Step 1:**
I used `WHEN=GROUP` with `BEGIN`, `END` and `PUSH` parameters.

```
//JOBNAME JOB ('ACCOUNT NAME'),'TRANSPOSE',          
//     CLASS=2,MSGCLASS=H,NOTIFY=&SYSUID             
//STEP1   EXEC PGM=SORT                              
//SORTIN  DD *                                       
DE001XYX   A                                         
CD100000   B                                         
CD200000   C                                         
DE001KKK   A                                         
CD100000   B                                         
DE003ZZZ   A                                         
DE001XYX   A                                         
CD100000   B                                         
CD200000   C                                         
DE001KKK   A                                         
CD100000   B                                         
//SORTOUT DD SYSOUT=*                                
//SYSOUT  DD SYSOUT=*                                
//SYSIN   DD *                                       
 SORT FIELDS=COPY                                    
 OUTREC IFTHEN=(WHEN=GROUP,BEGIN=(12,1,CH,EQ,C'A'),  
               END=(12,1,CH,EQ,C'C'),PUSH=(14:ID=1))
```

`PUSH=(14:ID=1)` means position 14 for 1 is an identifier that increments for each group. Each A indicates a new group regardless of whether the previous group was terminated with C. The identifier is +1'd when a new group is started.

**Note:** Since we are only allowing one character for the ID, when the ID counter gets to 10, a '0' will appear in position 14. You may also assign more than 1 byte for the ID.

**Output from the Step 1:**

```
********************************* TOP OF DATA **********************************
DE001XYX   A 1                                                                  
CD100000   B 1                                                                  
CD200000   C 1                                                                  
DE001KKK   A 2                                                                  
CD100000   B 2                                                                  
DE003ZZZ   A 3                                                                  
DE001XYX   A 4                                                                  
CD100000   B 4                                                                  
CD200000   C 4                                                                  
DE001KKK   A 5                                                                  
CD100000   B 5                                                                  
******************************** BOTTOM OF DATA ********************************
```

**Step 2:** Take the output from Step 1. Modify the position of DE, CD1 and CD2 records based on the three keys A, B and C respectively.

```
//JOBNAME JOB ('ACCOUNT NAME'),'TRANSPOSE',                     
//     CLASS=2,MSGCLASS=H,NOTIFY=&SYSUID                        
//STEP1   EXEC PGM=SORT                                         
//SORTIN  DD *                                                  
DE001XYX   A 1                                                  
CD100000   B 1                                                  
CD200000   C 1                                                  
DE001KKK   A 2                                                  
CD100000   B 2                                                  
DE003ZZZ   A 3                                                  
DE001XYX   A 4                                                  
CD100000   B 4                                                  
CD200000   C 4                                                  
DE001KKK   A 5                                                  
CD100000   B 5                                                  
//SORTOUT DD SYSOUT=*                                           
//SYSOUT  DD SYSOUT=*                                           
//SYSIN   DD *                                                  
 SORT FIELDS=COPY                                               
 OUTREC IFTHEN=(WHEN=(12,1,CH,EQ,C'A'),BUILD=(1:1,8,19Z,28:12,1,
               30:14,1)),                                       
        IFTHEN=(WHEN=(12,1,CH,EQ,C'B'),                         
               BUILD=(1:9Z,10:1,8,18:10Z,28:12,1,30:14,1)),     
        IFTHEN=(WHEN=(12,1,CH,EQ,C'C'),                         
               BUILD=(1:18Z,19:1,8,28:12,1,30:14,1))            
/*
```

**Note:** Binary zeros are inserted in between, as place holders so that they can be filled in with data, in Step 3.

**Output from Step 2:**

```
********************************* TOP OF DATA **********************************
DE001XYX                   A 1                                                  
         CD100000          B 1                                                  
                  CD200000 C 1                                                  
DE001KKK                   A 2                                                  
         CD100000          B 2                                                  
DE003ZZZ                   A 3                                                  
DE001XYX                   A 4                                                  
         CD100000          B 4                                                  
                  CD200000 C 4                                                  
DE001KKK                   A 5                                                  
         CD100000          B 5                                                  
******************************** BOTTOM OF DATA ********************************
```

With Hex mode ON, you will be able to see the binary zeros (X'00).

```
***************************** Top of Data ******************************
DE001XYX                   A 1                                          
CCFFFEEE0000000000000000000C4F444444444444444444444444444444444444444444
450017870000000000000000000101000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
----------------------------------------------------------------------- 
         CD100000          B 1                                          
000000000CCFFFFFF0000000000C4F444444444444444444444444444444444444444444
000000000341000000000000000201000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
----------------------------------------------------------------------- 
                  CD200000 C 1                                          
000000000000000000CCFFFFFF4C4F444444444444444444444444444444444444444444
000000000000000000342000000301000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
----------------------------------------------------------------------- 
DE001KKK                   A 2                                          
CCFFFDDD0000000000000000000C4F444444444444444444444444444444444444444444
450012220000000000000000000102000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
----------------------------------------------------------------------- 
         CD100000          B 2                                          
000000000CCFFFFFF0000000000C4F444444444444444444444444444444444444444444
000000000341000000000000000202000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
----------------------------------------------------------------------- 
DE003ZZZ                   A 3                                          
CCFFFEEE0000000000000000000C4F444444444444444444444444444444444444444444
450039990000000000000000000103000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
----------------------------------------------------------------------- 
DE001XYX                   A 4                                          
CCFFFEEE0000000000000000000C4F444444444444444444444444444444444444444444
450017870000000000000000000104000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
----------------------------------------------------------------------- 
         CD100000          B 4                                          
000000000CCFFFFFF0000000000C4F444444444444444444444444444444444444444444
000000000341000000000000000204000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
----------------------------------------------------------------------- 
                  CD200000 C 4                                          
000000000000000000CCFFFFFF4C4F444444444444444444444444444444444444444444
000000000000000000342000000304000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
DE001KKK                   A 5                                          
CCFFFDDD0000000000000000000C4F444444444444444444444444444444444444444444
450012220000000000000000000105000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
----------------------------------------------------------------------- 
         CD100000          B 5                                          
000000000CCFFFFFF0000000000C4F444444444444444444444444444444444444444444
000000000341000000000000000205000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
----------------------------------------------------------------------- 
**************************** Bottom of Data ****************************
```

**Step 3:**  With output from Step 2 as input, use `SUM FIELDS` to combine DE, CD1 and CD2 records of the group, with `SORT FIELDS` on the `ID` field in 30th Position.

```
//JOBNAME JOB ('ACCOUNT NAME'),'TRANSPOSE',                     
//     CLASS=2,MSGCLASS=H,NOTIFY=&SYSUID                        
//STEP1   EXEC PGM=SORT                                         
//SORTIN  DD *                                                  
DE001XYX                   A 1                                                  
         CD100000          B 1                                                  
                  CD200000 C 1                                                  
DE001KKK                   A 2                                                  
         CD100000          B 2                                                  
DE003ZZZ                   A 3                                                  
DE001XYX                   A 4                                                  
         CD100000          B 4                                                  
                  CD200000 C 4                                                  
DE001KKK                   A 5                                                  
         CD100000          B 5                                                  
//SORTOUT DD SYSOUT=*                                           
//SYSOUT  DD SYSOUT=*                                           
//SYSIN   DD *
  SORT FIELDS=(30,1,CH,A)                       
  SUM FIELDS=(1,8,10,8,19,8),FORMAT=BI          
  OUTREC FIELDS=(1:1,8,9:X,10:10,8,18:X,19:19,8)
/*
```

With `OUTREC FIELDS=(1:1,8,9:X,10:10,8,18:X,19:19,8)`, replace binary zeros in between DE, CD1 and CD2 fields with spaces.

**Output from Step 3:** Here you go!

```
***************************** Top of Data ******************************
DE001XYX CD100000 CD200000                                              
DE001KKK CD100000                                                       
DE003ZZZ                                                                
DE001XYX CD100000 CD200000                                              
DE001KKK CD100000                                                       
**************************** Bottom of Data ****************************
```

---

**More details on `SUM FIELDS` with Binary zeros:**

Binary addition operates on two bit patterns. Let's consider the following records (Hex mode is ON as I would like to show how Binary addition is being performed on the Hex values).

```
****** ********
000001 DE001XYX
       CCFFFEEE
       45001787
---------------
000002         
       00000000
       00000000
```

Hex value of the first byte, X'C4' is being added with the binary zeros in the 1st byte of 2nd record.

```
 C4
+00
 --
 C4
```

X'C4' denotes Letter 'D' in EBCDIC

If we change the Binary zero in the first byte to Binary one (X'01'), results will vary.

```
 C4
+01
 --
 C5
```

X'C5' denotes Letter 'E' in EBCDIC.

With Binary zeros we can perform `SUM FIELDS` on Alphanumeric data items (EBCDIC characters a-z, A-Z, 0-9) to group them onto one single record.

---

Comment: Thank you so much for your effort. Infact, Inposted this and forgot. I found the solution for this problem. But I have achieved that through JCL and BTEQ terdata querires.

Comment: Hi @user2959433 Good to know that you've found a solution. As Syncsort was tagged with the question, I considered using it to find the solution. It was quite challenging & unearthed new possibilities.