# Combine multiple records into one line based on first byte

Tags: mainframe, jcl

I need to combine multiple records into one single record. Each block of records to be merged (transposed) are marked by a numeric key. The delimiter can also be the record with the string CHG. I've tried resize but it mixes different 'blocks' of records. The number of 'tables' can be between 1 and 50. The LRECL of the input file is 60 So, if my input data looks like this:

```
1 CHG
1 DATA
1 MOTIVE
1 table1
1 table2
1 table3
2 CHG
2 DATA
2 MOTIVO
2 table1
3 CHG
3 DATA
3 MOTIVE
3 table1
3 table2
3 table3
3 table4
3 table5
```

The output should at least be:

```
1 CHG 1 DATA 1 MOTIVE 1 table1 1 table2 1 table3
2 CHG 2 DATA 2 MOTIVE 2 table1
3 CHG 3 DATA 3 MOTIVE 3 table1 3 table2 3 table3 3 table4 3 table5
```

The ideal output (I can remove the first byte of the records, if it helps)

```
1 CHG DATA MOTIVE table1
1 CHG DATA MOTIVE table2
1 CHG DATA MOTIVE table3
2 CHG DATA MOTIVE table1
3 CHG DATA MOTIVE table1 
3 CHG DATA MOTIVE table2
3 CHG DATA MOTIVE table3
3 CHG DATA MOTIVE table4
3 CHG DATA MOTIVE table5
```

These were my last attempts and none worked correctly:

```
 //TOOLIN   DD *                                            
    RESIZE FROM(INDD) TO(OUTDD1) TOLEN(600) USING(CTL1)       


  //TOOLIN   DD *                                            
     RESIZE FROM(INDD) TO(OUTDD1) TOLEN(600) USING(CTL1)       
  //CTL1CNTL DD  *                                           
     INREC BUILD=(1,50)                                       
     OUTFIL FNAMES=OUTDD1,OVERLAY=(1:1,600)
```

/*

Comment: Cannot be done using JCL as JCL does not manipulate data. You appear to be using DFSORT or SYNCSORT so the tag should be the appropriate one of those.

Answer (score 0):

I've just come up with the following SORT statements,

```
SORT FIELDS=(53,1,CH,A)
INREC IFTHEN=(WHEN=GROUP,BEGIN=(3,3,CH,EQ,C'CHG'),PUSH=(15:ID=1)),
  IFTHEN=(WHEN=(3,3,CH,EQ,C'CHG'),BUILD=(1,5,47Z,15,1)),
  IFTHEN=(WHEN=(3,4,CH,EQ,C'DATA'),BUILD=(6Z,3,4,42Z,15,1)),
  IFTHEN=(WHEN=(3,6,CH,EQ,C'MOTIVE'),BUILD=(11Z,3,6,35Z,15,1)),
  IFTHEN=(WHEN=(3,6,CH,EQ,C'TABLE1'),BUILD=(18Z,3,6,28Z,15,1)),
  IFTHEN=(WHEN=(3,6,CH,EQ,C'TABLE2'),BUILD=(25Z,3,6,21Z,15,1)),
  IFTHEN=(WHEN=(3,6,CH,EQ,C'TABLE3'),BUILD=(32Z,3,6,14Z,15,1)),
  IFTHEN=(WHEN=(3,6,CH,EQ,C'TABLE4'),BUILD=(39Z,3,6,7Z,15,1)),
  IFTHEN=(WHEN=(3,6,CH,EQ,C'TABLE5'),BUILD=(46Z,3,6,15,1))
SUM FIELDS=(1,8,9,8,17,8,25,8,33,8,41,8,49,4),FORMAT=BI
ALTSEQ CODE=(0040)
OUTREC FIELDS=(1,52,TRAN=ALTSEQ)
```

Input:

```
1 CHG
1 DATA
1 MOTIVE
1 TABLE1
1 TABLE2
1 TABLE3
2 CHG
2 DATA
2 MOTIVE
2 TABLE1
3 CHG
3 DATA
3 MOTIVE
3 TABLE1
3 TABLE2
3 TABLE3
3 TABLE4
3 TABLE5
```

Output:

```
1 CHG DATA MOTIVE TABLE1 TABLE2 TABLE3
2 CHG DATA MOTIVE TABLE1
3 CHG DATA MOTIVE TABLE1 TABLE2 TABLE3 TABLE4 TABLE5
```

I've used my favourite `WHEN=GROUP` feature and binary addition technique in `DFSORT` to achieve this outcome. More details about these features & technique can be found in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52177771/4626398) of mine in SO, as it also suggests a solution for a Record Transpose problem.

`ALTSEQ CODE` is being used additionally to convert any unused Binary zeros to spaces in the final output.

Although I believe this answer provides you the basic idea of acheiving your output, you might have to repeat the `INREC IFTHEN` clause for tables from 6 to 50.

Hope this helps.